# Javascript onclick function not working . Showing error [object object] in output

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the input which to be entered in txtBox as input:

```
<!-- <#assign SEMFirmNameAlt = " - ${site.data.SEMFirmNameAlt}">
    <#if site.data.SEMFirmNameAlt = "">
        <#assign SEMFirmNameAlt = "">
    </#if> -->
```

Here is the entire code::

```
<textarea type="text" id="txtBox" ></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Process String" onclick="processString()" style="width:250px" />
<br /><br />
<textarea id="txtArea" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>

<script>
    function processString() {
          document.getElementById("txtArea").value = "";
          var comments = $("txtBox").contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeName === "#comment"
          });
          var result = $(comments[0]).replaceWith(function(){
            return document.createTextNode(this.data);
          });
          if (result != null){
            document.getElementById("txtArea").value = result;
          }
    }     
</script>
```

What's wrong in this javascript code ? Error is showing [object object]. The output should be UNCOMMENT the input data and shown in "txtArea" .

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjVWwB

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Result is an object. What are did you want it to be?

Comment: Please explain what you expect this code to do. It really doesn't make much sense. `result` is a jQuery object and you have incorrect selectors and a textarea has no descendents to use `contents()` on

Comment: Rather than an alert, try a `console.log(result)`. That way you can see what the result actually is.

Comment: The user will enter that top data as input  in "txtBox". When user click "Process string" button.. then the output should be shown in "txtArea" section.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed function:

```
function processString() {
  var txtArea = document.getElementById("txtArea"); 
  txtArea.value = "";
  var comments = $($('#txtBox').val());

  var valueStripped = '';  
  comments.filter(function () {
    return this.nodeName == "#comment";
  }).each(function (index, value) {
    valueStripped += value.data;
  });

  if (valueStripped != ''){
    txtArea.value = valueStripped;
  }
}
```

This is fixed Codepen link:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLrxvw

Comment: Great, if it worked as expected, mark as answered :)

Comment: One problem is there Buli. If I'm putting a large block of code in txtBox, then only "comment[0]" should uncomment and other codes should be there in output. But nothing is showing in output. Any idea ?

Comment: I've updated the link and the answer. It will add only comment nodes. If you need something else it would  to write here value that you are pasting into the textbox.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjVWwB, here i've updated the large block html codes in HTML section. Please take from this link. The last "comment[4]" should uncomment only.. and output should be "comment[4]" part, along with the other codes.

Comment: Sorry it's not so clear what should be input and what is expected output now. Can you try to update the question with input block and expected block ?

Comment: Buli.. Please see that link again.  
codepen.io/anon/pen/BjVWwB . User needs to enter the code which inside the <head> section. Output will be again the total code except the last comment which should be UNCOMMENTED only. Check the codepen CSS section, i've updated the desired output.

Comment: Hi Lipak,
I've update the codepen. It includes other nodes and their values now. Only wrapper html tag is missing and i'm don't have idea how to fix it expect to manually add it to the result string.